# Excel macro to extract specific data

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

I have a spreadsheet with a cell which contains every app on a computer. I want a macro to extract a specific application from the list and delete the rest of the apps and simply display the application I want in the same or next cell.

For example the cell data looks like this:

> "Microsoft Office Project Professional 2010 - 14.0.6029.1000"; "Security Update for Microsoft Office 2010 (KB2598039) 32-Bit Edition"; "Security Update for Microsoft Office 2010 (KB2553091)"; "Definition update for Microsoft Office 2010 (KB982726) 32-Bit Edition"; "Update for Microsoft Office 2010 (KB2553455) 32-Bit Edition"; "Update for Microsoft Office 2010 (KB2494150)"; "Update for Microsoft Office 2010 (KB2553181) 32-Bit Edition"; "Microsoft Project 2010 Service Pack 1 (SP1)";

I would like it to search the cell for any version of "Microsoft Office Project" then delete the rest of the cell text and display Microsoft Office Project Professional 2010 - 14.0.6029.1000.

I don't know where to begin as I've never created a macro. Any ideas how I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a formula solution.  If the text is in `A1`, you can enter the following in `B1`:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("Microsoft Office Project",A1),FIND("""",A1,FIND("Microsoft Office Project",A1))-FIND("Microsoft Office Project",A1))
```

Comment: Thanks very much, that works well just need to tweak it a little. Much appreciated

Comment: How could I tweak he formula to respond with a 0 or something else if it doesnt find anything. It seems to bring down the result from the box above if nothing is found?

Comment: It should throw an error if nothing is found.  Perhaps you missed an `A1` in the formula when tweaking it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution which displays "not found" if the search string could not be found:

> =IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("Microsoft Office Project Professional",A1)),MID(A1,FIND("Microsoft Office Project
>   Professional",A1),FIND("""",A1,FIND("Microsoft Office Project
>   Professional",A1)+1)-FIND("Microsoft Office Project
>   Professional",A1)),"not found")